# Using more than 6 symbols available as default in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, settings, data-visualization

I have 8 variables that I would like to plot on a PCAplot using ggplot. Ggplot will only let me use 6 by default.

I am aware of the function scale_shape_manual but I would like to find a way to change the ggplot setting so that it automatically apply to every plot.

I would like to avoid having to insert a "scale_shape_manual" specification for each of my plot. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make your own function. For example,

```
my_ggplot <- function(...) {
  ggplot(...) + scale_color_distiller(palette = 2)
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, hp, col = cyl)) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]

```
my_ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, hp, col = cyl)) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image]